# Tomcat 7 virtual hosts disappear after restart

Tags: tomcat, hosting, web-hosting, website, tomcat7

Currently I am using tomcat 7 to host two websites. To do this, I simply create two virtual hosts using the `host-manager` (part of `tomcat7-admin`). But, when I restart the server, the hosts seem to disappear and not reload. The web apps for each respect website stay there but the hosts do not load in. Does anyone know why this happens and what could be done to keep the hosts persistent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your virtual hosts in server.xml.

Reference: [Bug 48674](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48674)